# Android Webview doesn't load on version 2.3.6

Tags: android, webview

I have a standard webview application that fails to load on 2.3.6 android version.
The code I user is the following

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     this.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.screen);
     this.clearCache();
     this.clearHistory();

     if (isNetworkAvailable())
        super.loadUrl("https://url/index.html");            
     else 
         super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/noconnection.html");  }
```

it loads the splash screens and then displays only blank screen. Any idea?

Comment: I suppose it's problem of particular web site not `Android` system. Does it load in mobile browser?

Comment: Yes it loads in browser correctly and the problem is only in 2.3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually related with ssl. I was loading https and had to accept the ssl certificate in code. See here: http://antonylees.blogspot.gr/2012/11/how-to-bypass-ssl-certificate-checking.html